# How to set a video as background to the root in python tkinter? or make it independent from other widgets acting as background

Tags: python, tkinter, video, background

I want to set a video as the background of my app only for the main screen. The rest of the app is composed of a menu bar and notebook widget. Nothing else. If we cant achieve this, it is OK that the video acts as a background which I mean that I want its size not to be changed by the other widgets.

Here is my code.

```
__init__ ;)->smiley
    video_name = "images/noor.mp4"
    self.video = imageio.get_reader(video_name)
    my_label = tk.Label(self)
    my_label.pack()
    thread = threading.Thread(target=self.stream, args=(my_label,))
    thread.daemon = 1
    thread.start()
def stream(self,label):

    for image in self.video.iter_data():
        frame_image = ImageTk.PhotoImage(Image.fromarray(image),size=[1300,500])
        label.config(image=frame_image)
        label.image = frame_image
```

Comment: Did you try `my_label.place(...)` instead of `my_label.pack()`?

Comment: @acw1668 yes I tried but I could not manage it